# Cambiar el icono por defecto de NotificationCompat.Builder Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

Quiero cambiar el icono de notificación que sale por defecto.

Tengo mi *NotificationCompat.Builder* así:

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.largeicon);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallicon)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setColor(0x00)
                    .setContentTitle("B-TRAKER")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentText("Abrir aplicación");
```

El caso es que no se cambia por el icono que he establecido. Investigando un poco miré que para que se muestren los iconos debo cambiar el *targetSdkVersion* del Gradle a 20, pero aún así sigue sin mostrarme el icono que quiero. Solo muestra el icono por defecto de Android (el androide).

Edito: Bueno, al parecer estaba bien mi parte de código, he reiniciado el dispositivo y ahora si me coge los iconos.

Comment: Prueba de esta manera, no lo pongo como respuesta ya que no puedo probarlo ahora mismo: **Notification notification=mBuilder.build()
notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(android.R.id.icon, R.drawable.largeicon);**

Comment: Creo que debes colocar los iconos en la carpeta `mipmap` del proyecto, no en drawable. Prueba algo como esto: `.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))` si te funciona, cambia `ic_launcher` por el nombre de tu icono, una vez guardado en mipmap por supuesto.

Comment: @Israel no se como aplicar eso ahí como lo tengo yo. Sustituyéndolo todo?
Ya probé de esa manera y nada. Ya sustituí los iconos por defecto, el icono de la App si que me lo cambia, pero no el de notificación.

Comment: Pones eso que puse, y en la parte que tienes **mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());** reemplazas mBuilder.build() por notification. Si no funciona prueba lo que dice @A.Cedano y si tampoco, Comenta en que version de android estas probando para probar yo y darte una respuesta funcionando.

Comment: @JuanAlbertoCarrascoGalán que icono no es visible el Small o Large???

Comment: Ninguno es visible, el pequeñito que aparece en la barra de notificaciones y el grande que aparece al desplegarla. Lo pruebo en 5.1.1 de Android, tengo compileSdkVersion 25 y targetSdkVersion 20 (antes estaba a 25)

Answer (score 1):

Las imágenes que cargas no son las imágenes por defecto, las  imágenes por defecto se encuentran dentro del directorio `/mipmap`/ y se llaman `ic_launcher.png` y tu notificación se vería de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema conocido en Android 5.0 es que tus notificaciones se vean de esta manera y es relacionado a que no es una imagen con transparencia, al parecer ya eliminaron esta información de la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero si el problema es que no se visualiza la imagen puede ser que en algún folder no exista la imagen de la densidad requerida.**

```
res/
    drawable/   
        largeicon.png
        smallicon.png    
    drawable-mdpi/  

        smallicon.png  
    drawable-hdpi/  

    drawable-xhdpi/  
        largeicon.png
        smallicon.png  
    drawable-xxhdpi/  
        smallicon.png
```

Comment: Entonces que debería hacer? Que densidad tendría que coger para mi icono?

Answer (score -1):

Usa:

```
.setIcon(R.drawable.smallicon)
```